# Making a dummy column based on a range of values with a huge data set

Tags: r, if-statement, dataset, multiple-columns, large-data

I want to sort my data based on a column's range of values. My data is large, but I have made a small data set as a working example:

```
 cats   colour  length  weight      mew
     1        5        3      3      0      
     2        4        4      2      0  
     3        3        5      3      0  
     4        2        9      4      1
     5        4       22      1      1 
     43       43             90      0
     22
     15               32     45
     25
              32      23       4     0
     35       2       29
```

Here is my **broken** code that is supposed to sort based on a column and adds a dummy column based on the column's value:

```
x <- data$cats  # how to refer to a column: name_of_data_set_$_what column you want e.g. data$mass

x$dog <- ifelse(x$x>0 & x$x>3)

animal <- function(x) { 

  if ( x > 0 | x <3) {

  return(cbind( data , dog = 0))  

  } else { if (x > 4 | x < 6) {

  return(cbind( data , dog = 1))

  } else {

  return(cbind( data , dog = 2))

  }
  }
  }


animal(x)
summary(animal)



dput(head(data, 10))



animal(x)
```

What the code is supposed to do:

So column was 1, 2, 3 and 4 should look like this:

```
 cats   colour  length  weight      mew     dog
     1        5        3      3      0      0      
     2        4        4      2      0      0
     3        3        5      3      0      0
     4        2        9      4      1      1
     5        4       22      1      1             
     43       43             90      0
     22
     15               32     45
     25
              32      23       4     0
     35       2       29
```

Comment: Re-read with `data <- read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and try again. Additionally, there's no sorting happening in your function.

Comment: Please post reproducible data with the output from `dput(head(data, 10))` and I'll explain further.

Comment: i added that code to the bottom :                                                                                                                               structure(list(cats.colour.length.weight.mew = structure(c(3L, 
5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c(",43,,,", "0,23,1,,1", 
"1,5,3,3,0", "13,1,,2,", "2,4,4,20,1", "23,11,,,", "3,3,5,30,0", 
"4,2,9,43,0", "5,1,4,22,1"), class = "factor")), .Names = "cats.colour.length.weight.mew", row.names = c(NA, 
9L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say to post the **result** from `dput(data)`. Please also post the result from `animal(x)`

Answer (score 1):

I think your filter criterias are not consistent and you mixed up your if else statements a little. I don't know, if this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
x <- data.frame(cat=1:10)

x$dog <- ifelse(x$cat > 0 & x$cat <= 3, 0,
                ifelse(x$cat >= 4 & x$cat <= 6, 1, 2))

# output is
   cat dog
1    1   0
2    2   0
3    3   0
4    4   1
5    5   1
6    6   1
7    7   2
8    8   2
9    9   2
10  10   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Please stop changing the original post.  To users viewing this post for the first time, it makes the answers look like fixes to problems that never existed.

**Question:** Is the file you're reading from comma-delimited?

---

There are a couple of obvious issues with your original post.

Let's start with this the output from `dput` (which should be moved from comments to the original post for others to easily see).

```
structure(list(cats.colour.length.weight.mew = ## that's not right
               structure(c(3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 4L), 
               .Label = c(",43,,,", "0,23,1,,1", "1,5,3,3,0", "13,1,,2,", 
                          "2,4,4,20,1", "23,11,,,", "3,3,5,30,0", 
                          "4,2,9,43,0", "5,1,4,22,1"), 
               class = "factor")),
          .Names = "cats.colour.length.weight.mew",  ## that's not right
          row.names = c(NA, 9L), 
          class = "data.frame")
```

When read from a file with `read.csv`, R classes the `character` string columns as `factor` variables by default. R sees factors differently than it sees numeric or character elements.  In turn, sorting does not work in the same manner with factor variables.

Try using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
data <- read.csv("filename.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

<strike>Next, your function should only have one `return` statement at the very end.  Assign a variable in the `if-else` statements and return the variable.</strike>

**ADDED** I'm actually not certain about the above statement.  Need to do some further research.

Also, there's no need for a `{` between `else` and `if` in `else if (x > 4 | x < 6)`

```
animal <- function(x)
{ 
    if ( x > 0 | x < 3 ){
        return(cbind( data , dog = 0))
    } else if (x > 4 | x < 6){
        return(cbind( data , dog = 1))
    } else {
        return(cbind( data , dog = 2))
    }
    ## return(y) removed 
}
```

Third, `animal` is defined as a function, not a variable.  And `summary(animal)` does not call to your function.  To call, use `animal(x)`.  A summary, then, can be obtained with `summary(animal(x))`

**That's as much as I can tell you until I'm able to reproduce your data.  Please move the `dput` output in the comments to the original post so everyone looking at this question sees it.**

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want to do... try `sort` or `order` from R

for example

```
x <- read.table("test.txt",header=T,sep="\t")
x[order(x$cats),]
```

UPDATE: it's still not very clear from your code what you compare with what...but try this

```
x$dog <- ifelse(x$PUT_YOUR_PARAMS_THERE>0 & x$ANOTHER_PARAM >1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: I want to insert a value into a new column based on each value that the column cat has

Comment: 2 new  errors:                                                                                                                                     Error in object[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Error in if (x > 0 | x < 3) { : argument is of length zero

Comment: i did and I get: Error in if (x > 0 | x < 3) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(x, 0) : > not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(x, 3) : < not meaningful for factors
3: In if (x > 0 | x < 3) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   thanks for helping though. I added your code above x: x$dog <- ifelse(x$x>0 & x$x>3) and I got that error. i'm staying on this page :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new variable that is based on ranges of an existing variable then look at the `cut` and `findInterval` functions.  You should only need one of them, but they work a little differently from each other.

Also I think that you have the meaning of `|` and `&` reversed in your code above and the `ifelse` function should have 3 arguments to be meaningful.